# Export questions and feedback from Google Forms to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I've [learned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571874/is-it-possible-to-export-questions-and-multiple-choice-options-from-a-google-for/58590670#58590670?newreg=6f992d6cf0a144c59008d532496fd2a2) to create a script to import all questions from a Google Form to a Google Sheet.

What do I need to add to the script to export the feedback from each question as well?

I've tried this [in Alberto Vielma's script]:

```
var question = el.asMultipleChoiceItem();
var choices = question.getChoices();
sheet.getRange(question_position +1, 1).setValue(question.getTitle());
var i = 0;


for (i; i < choices.length; i++){
  sheet.getRange(answers_position + 1, 2).setValue(choices[i].getValue());
  sheet.getRange(answers_position + 1, 3).setValue(choices[i].isCorrectAnswer());
  sheet.getRange(answers_position + 1, 4).setValue(question.getFeedbackForCorrect());
  sheet.getRange(answers_position + 1, 5).setValue(question.getFeedbackForIncorrect());
  answers_position++;
```

but the two last colums just return `"FreebirdFeedback"` to the sheet, and not the actual feedback. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're just setting an instance of `QuizFeedback` as a value. If you want to retrieve the text that is shown to the user after they've submitted a response, you should use its [getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/quiz-feedback#getText()) method:

```js
.setValue(question.getFeedbackForCorrect().getText());
.setValue(question.getFeedbackForIncorrect().getText());
```

#### Reference:

- [Class QuizFeedback](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/quiz-feedback)

Comment: Thank you @lamlichus ! it worked!