# RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED when extracting from Google Form to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to extract questions and multiple choice options of a Google Form to a Google Sheet. I've found a solution here ([Is it possible to export questions and multiple choice options from a Google Form to a Google Sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571874/is-it-possible-to-export-questions-and-multiple-choice-options-from-a-google-for)), in the answer by alberto vielma (answer of Oct 28 '19 at 12:06).

However, I'm running into an error ("We're sorry, there was an unexpected error while creating the Cloud Platform project. Error code RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED.") when trying Alberto's script.

This surprised me, because I've used the script succesfully a few months ago... Does anyone have an idea what exactly went wrong?

(I created a new topic, because the 'tips' about answering suggested I shouldn't "contribute" to above mentioned topic if I only had extra questions.)

For your convenience, I'll copy Alberto's script here:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('YOUR-FORM-ID');
// Open a sheet by ID.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YOUR-SHEET-ID').getSheets()[0];

// variables for putting the questions and answers in the right position
var question_position = 0;
var answers_position = 0;

// main function to run
function getFormValues() {
  form.getItems().forEach(callback);
}

// Iterate over all questions 
function callback(el){
  
  // check if the question is multiple choice
  if (el.getType() == FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE) {
    // change the type from Item to MultipleChoiceItem
    var question = el.asMultipleChoiceItem();
    var choices = question.getChoices();
    // set the title of the question in the cell
    sheet.getRange(question_position +1, 1).setValue(question.getTitle());
    
    var i = 0;
    // set the answers in the right cells
    for (i; i < choices.length; i++){
      sheet.getRange(answers_position + 1, 2).setValue(choices[i].getValue());
      answers_position++;
    }
    question_position += i;
    answers_position++;
  }
  question_position++;
  
}
```

Comment: I create my forms from a spreadsheet. I allow the user to select a response in the same spreadsheet or not and populate the ss with the answers. I cannot populate 'short answers' in the form but pretty much everything else works. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Amy8LgeCdl8RsDr98pEVXVSqrMzGqMc_VuLYQy94mC8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue impacting some users earlier today (which appears to be no longer persistent.) Ref https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194826559?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

Was there any value written to your spreadsheet when you got the error?

I wonder it deal with usage limits because you have many `setValue` to spreadsheet.

Maybe you can try to first push the all single values (questions and choices) to an array `values`. And finally use [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to reduce the number of calls of `setValue`.

Or you could try to add some [Utilies.sleep(milliseconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) in each loop.